# Grails 2.0 - Upgrading Controller Testing and losing renderArgs and redirectArgs

Tags: grails-2.0

Problem: 
I upgraded from Grails 1.3.7 to Grails 2.0. 
I had to then refactor my controller tests to use annotations: @TestFor(controller) and Mock(domain) which took care of a lot of problems.
However, in 1.3.7 controller.renderArgs and controller.redirectArgs were available. This seems to no longer be the case in 2.0 and I am having a difficult time figuring out how to get the  data these very convenient variables provided.

It appears that this data will not be provided based off of [this Grails Jira posting](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7617). The last comment in this post by James Lang, which has no response, is my exact question:

In Grails 2.0 controller unit testing, how can you get to the renderArgs such as action, id, params, etc?

The Jira comments only supply inputs to getting to the response.redirectUrl

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the update and the link to the post by Graeme.

Our solution to the problem was to metaclass the controller to get to these variables. 
I created corresponding member variables and then added the following code to the setup of the unit test:

```
    controller.metaClass.redirect = { Map map ->
        redirectAction = map.action
        redirectID = map.id
        redirectUrl = map.url
    }

    controller.metaClass.render = {Map map ->
        renderView = map.view
        renderModel = map.model
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it appears you can't.  I saw [this forum post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/controller-redirectArgs-equivalent-in-Grails-2-0-unit-tests-td3768216.html) where Graeme replied and mentioned it would take a feature request.

Comment: Consider issue raised then since it caused much refactoring. Thanks fo r the post.